# Rewriting Gimli_hash in Java

Tags: java, c, hash

I'm attempting to rewrite Gimli_hash from C to Java.

I've checked my rewrite of the Gimli permutation against both the c code and the test vectors, and it is correct, so the problem lies somewhere in my rewrite of the actual hash, although I can't figure out where.

```
void Gimli_hash(const uint8_t *input,
                uint64_t inputByteLen,
                uint8_t *output,
                uint64_t outputByteLen)
{
    uint32_t state[12];
    uint8_t* state_8 = (uint8_t*)state;
    uint64_t blockSize = 0;
    uint64_t i;

    // === Initialize the state ===
    memset(state, 0, sizeof(state));

    // === Absorb all the input blocks ===
    while(inputByteLen > 0) {
        blockSize = MIN(inputByteLen, rateInBytes);
        for(i=0; i<blockSize; i++)
            state_8[i] ^= input[i];
        input += blockSize;
        inputByteLen -= blockSize;

        if (blockSize == rateInBytes) {
            gimli(state);
            blockSize = 0;
        }
    }

    // === Do the padding and switch to the squeezing phase ===
    state_8[blockSize] ^= 0x1F;
    // Add the second bit of padding
    state_8[rateInBytes-1] ^= 0x80;
    // Switch to the squeezing phase
    gimli(state);

    // === Squeeze out all the output blocks ===
    while(outputByteLen > 0) {
        blockSize = MIN(outputByteLen, rateInBytes);
        memcpy(output, state, blockSize);
        output += blockSize;
        outputByteLen -= blockSize;

        if (outputByteLen > 0)
            gimli(state);
    }
}
```

This is taken directly from the C implementation of Gimli,
 and here is the Java code I've managed to put together:

```
public static byte[] hash(byte[] input, int outputLen) {
        int inputlen = input.length;

        int[] state = new int[12];
        byte[] state_8 = stateToBytes(state);
        int blocksize = 0;
        int i;

        int pointer = 0;

        /* Absorbing input */
        while (inputlen > 0) {
            blocksize = Math.min(inputlen, rateInBytes);
            for (i = 0; Integer.compareUnsigned(i, blocksize) < 0; i++) {
                state_8[i] ^= input[i + pointer];
            }
            state = stateToInt(state_8);

            pointer += blocksize;
            inputlen -= blocksize;

            if (blocksize == rateInBytes) {
                gimli(state);
                state_8 = stateToBytes(state);
                blocksize = 0;
            }
        }

        state_8[blocksize] ^= 0x1f;
        state_8[rateInBytes - 1] ^= 0x80;
        state = stateToInt(state_8);
        gimli(state);
        state_8 = stateToBytes(state);

        byte[] output = new byte[outputLen];
        int outputPointer = 0;

        while (outputLen > 0) {
            blocksize = Math.min(outputLen, rateInBytes);
            System.arraycopy(state_8, 0, output, outputPointer, blocksize);
            outputPointer += blocksize;
            outputLen -= blocksize;

            if (outputLen > 0) {
                gimli(state);
                state_8 = stateToBytes(state);
            }
        }

        return output;
    }
```

The stateToInt and stateToBytes simply converts between the byte format of the state and the int format (because the permutation operates on the int format but the hash on the byte format). When hashing an empty string (0 bytes), the C implementation returns b0634b2c0b082aedc5c0a2fe4ee3adcfc989ec05de6f00addb04b3aaac271f67, and the Java code returns 4b7f6da2d5a901dbdb580a08647e16ae11163288593da0ba29d88ce8926af025.

Any help on figuring out where the Java implementation is diverging from the C one would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you made absolutely sure that the `stateToInt` and `stateToBytes` functions have the exact behavior as your C program would have?  Is your `int` actually 32-bits?  Do those functions have defined behavior if performing shifts on potentially negative values?  You should probe deeper than just looking at the final output for empty string.  Compare the internal state values at every single step in both versions, to find where things start to go wrong.

Comment: @paddy , as far as I know, all shift behavior is defined in Java and all ints are 32 bits. I already took the potential negative shifts into account by using the unsigned right shift (>>>) available in Java. I'll attempt to go through all the state values. As for the stateToInt and stateToBytes, I'm not exactly sure what the C code is doing with regards to that, so if the C code is simply treating the integer array as a byte array and vice versa, then those methods are correct.

Comment: Please provide the `stateToBytes` and `stateToInt`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the reason the hash wasn't working was a matter of endianness:
The original stateToBytes and stateToInt wasn't working because it was in BE instead of LE:
Original:

```
private static byte[] stateToBytes(int[] state) {
        byte[][] temp = new byte[state.length][];

        for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
            temp[i] = intToBytes(state[i]);
        }

        return merge(temp);
    }

    private static int[] stateToInt(byte[] state) {
        int[] out = new int[state.length / 4];
        for (int i = 0; i < (state.length / 4); i++) {
            out[i] = byteArrayToInt(Arrays.copyOfRange(state, (i * 4), ((i + 1) * 4)));
        }

        return out;
    }
```

Updated:

```
private static byte[] stateToBytes(int[] state) {
        byte[][] temp = new byte[state.length][];

        for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
            temp[i] = reverse(intToBytes(state[i]));
        }

        return merge(temp);
    }

    private static int[] stateToInt(byte[] state) {
        int[] out = new int[state.length / 4];
        for (int i = 0; i < (state.length / 4); i++) {
            out[i] = byteArrayToInt(reverse(Arrays.copyOfRange(state, (i * 4), ((i + 1) * 4))));
        }

        return out;
    }
```

Thanks @paddy for bringing my attention to the behavior of those functions.